# "Bendy" screwdriver

Tags: tools, screws

I've got some screws right next to the geyser and there’s no space to get a screwdriver in. I'm guessing they were originally inserted before the geyser was installed.

Is there such a thing as a "bendy" or flexible screwdriver so that I can effectively work at right angles?

Sounds crazy but it's the only thing I can think off!

Comment: What's a geyser?

Comment: I'm assuming it's not [this kind of geyser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geyser).

Comment: Aha! Thank you Wikipedia for your [disambiguation pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geyser_(disambiguation)). Looks like it's a water heating system.

Comment: Yes - in NZ it's the device that heats domestic hot water.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [right-angle screwdriver](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000XYOUS6) will probably work for your situation. They're also fairly inexpensive.

[image]

As for "bendy" screwdrivers, they do make them under the label "flexible shaft screwdrivers," but most of them have [pretty low ratings on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=tools&field-keywords=flexible%20screwdriver&x=0&y=0). The best one appears to be the [EazyPower Flex Extension](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002BC0U0), which is meant to be used with a drill.

Comment: The problem with a truly bendy driver is transferring the torque consistently.

Comment: you can get a cheap right angle screwdriver at any hardware store of a couple of bucks. Not as fancy as the kit above.

Comment: [Less fancy version](http://www.b2b-trade.net/shops/product/Draper-2-Piece-Plain-Slot-Pz-Type-Angled-Screwdriver-Set.html)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for but I guess I'll have to import it!

Answer (score 5):

If you have a small ratchet set and screwdriver bits, you can chuck a 1/4" (I believe) socket into the ratchet and then slide the appropriate screwdriver bit into the socket.

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is only to remove something that's attached there, you should also consider using a hacksaw to cut the screws.

Comment: What if you decide removing the something wasn't a good idea? Then you're stuck with the challenge of finding a right angle screw extractor as well as a right angle screwdriver.